# Java version of TinyGP, its output and testing data

Tags: java, genetic-programming

I am studying the Java version of TinyGP.

I read the book "A field guide to genetic programming" (readable [here](http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/staff/rpoli/TinyGP/)) but I did not understand what is "X1" in it's output?

Is there any way that I can test for any data and get an output (i.e., prediction) based on data file given already as an input?

Answer (score 1):

TinyGP accepts a user-specified number of input variables, which are labeled X1 through XN. So X1 refers to the first column of data that you provided. When it shows up in the output, it means that the best program evolved will replace that location in the code with whatever the value of X1 is for the current set of inputs.

It doesn't look like there is a way within TinyGP to run new data through evolved programs, but since the output includes the best program evolved it's pretty easy to do. The programs are represented as expression trees, so they can be evaluate as mathematical equations.

Let's look at the best program from the second generation in the example from the book you linked to: `( ( ( - 0.3839867944222206 / -2.2796127162428403 ) + ( -1.8386812853617673 / -1.06553859601892 ) ) - ( ( ( 4.984026635222818 * ( 0.17196413319878445 - 0.1294044215655923 ) ) + ( X1 - -1.8956001614031734 ) ) * 0.3627020733460027 ) )`.

If you plug the value from the first column of the data that you want to evaluate into the location in this equation where `X1` currently is and plug it into a calculator, you will get a number, which is this program's answer for that set of input data.

For example, let's say that we want to evaluate the last data point in the example input from the webpage: `6.2 -0.0830894028174964`. This data point has `6.2`  as its value for `X1` and `-0.0830894028174964` as its target value. Plugging `6.2` into the equation, we get: `( ( ( - 0.3839867944222206 / -2.2796127162428403 ) + ( -1.8386812853617673 / -1.06553859601892 ) ) - ( ( ( 4.984026635222818 * ( 0.17196413319878445 - 0.1294044215655923 ) ) + ( 6.2 - -1.8956001614031734 ) ) * 0.3627020733460027 ) )`. A calculator can tell us that this equals `−1.119194367`. This estimate is pretty bad (it's `−1.036104964` units off from the target), but this solution was taken from the second generation, so that's to be expected.

Comment: thanks a lot......... But I'm still confused...the first column contains a lot of values. Which value in the first column should replace "X1" to evaluate a number???

Comment: For instance, if you wanted to get the answer for the first entry in the example (in section 2 here http://cswww.essex.ac.uk/staff/rpoli/TinyGP/), you would substitute in 1, whereas for the second line you would substitute in 0.0, and for the third 0.1, and so on.

Comment: Each number in X1 (ie each row in the table) corresponds to a different data point that you might want to estimate an answer for. So whichever one you want to calculate an answer for is the one you should choose.